# FMDB executeUpdate not altering database

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, fmdb

Inserting new items to the table works perfectly, updating however has no effect.

I am using the following statement to update my db.

```
BOOL success = [fmDB executeUpdate:@"UPDATE activities SET type = ?, author = '?', 
                time = '?', location = '?', node = '?', nodeID = ? 
                WHERE itemid = ?", [NSNumber numberWithInt:itemType], author, 
                time, location, node, [NSNumber numberWithInt:nodeID], 
                [NSNumber numberWithInt:itemID], nil];
```

Everything that hasn't been wrapped as an NSNumber is an NSString (which all log out as expected).

I receive 0 errors when the command is run (the success bool returns TRUE)

The next time I read my db, the changes have not been made.

Any ideas?

Comment: I hope the database is not in the app bundle, but somewhere where it's writable...

Comment: The db is on the device - /var/mobile/Applications/*/Documents/FeedItems.db , like I said, I can insert to it, just not update items that already exist.

Comment: trace execution also seems to be logging out the correct statement being fired

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499614/ios-sqlite-fmdb-update-not-working

Comment: In the link you provide the solution was that the update query was not seperated by commas, mine were

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I got it to work.. some how..

```
 BOOL success = [fmDB executeUpdateWithFormat:@"UPDATE activites 
   SET type = %@, node = %@, time = %@, location = %@, author = %@, 
   nodeID = %@ WHERE itemid = %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:itemType], 
   node, time, location, author, [NSNumber numberWithInt:nodeID], 
   [NSNumber numberWithInt:itemID], nil];
```

This didn't work until I'd removed the ' ' s from around the string objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if([db open])
 {
    NSString *queryStr ;
    queryStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Update activities SET type = ?, author = '?', 
            time = '?', location = '?', node = '?', nodeID = ? 
            WHERE itemid = ? ",[NSNumber numberWithInt:itemType], author, 
            time, location, node, [NSNumber numberWithInt:nodeID], 
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:itemID]];
    [db executeUpdate:queryStr];
    NSLog(@"UPDATE\n%@",queryStr);
  }
```

Comment: You can't use '?' in [NSString stringWithFormat:], you have to use %@ if you want to do it that way. This is essentially doing nothing different from what I am doing except calling executeUpdate twice, no changes saved.